# Unable to convert phone to string in apex

Tags: apex, rest-api, rest, string

I am working on rest API services. I need to push phone number as a string in the body of the request.

I tried following way.

```
String Str1=ts.phone.replaceAll('(','');
String Str2=Str1.replaceAll(')','');
String Str3=Str2.replaceAll('-','');
```

But I'm getting the following error

> System.StringException: Invalid regex: Unclosed group near index 1

Please let me know how to convert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just strip out anything that is not a digit e.g.

```
String cphone = '(800) 555-1234';
String s = cphone.replaceAll('\\D','');
```

then if you want to format back to a US number, you can do something like this:

```
if (s.length() == 10) {
String sphone = '(' + s.substring(0, 3) + ') ' + s.substring(3, 6) + '-' + s.substring(6);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the `(` and `)`

```
String Str1=phone.replaceAll('\\(','');
String Str2=Str1.replaceAll('\\)','');
```

The following:

```
String phone = '(800) 555-1212';
String Str1=phone.replaceAll('\\(','');
String Str2=Str1.replaceAll('\\)','');
String Str3=Str2.replaceAll('-','');
System.debug(Str3);
```

Outputs

> 800 5551212

Some previous discussion on this located on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399078/what-special-characters-must-be-escaped-in-regular-expressions)